# I generate 2 arrays of equal length (15), with a choice of 4 possible letters at each position - why do they come back 53% to 87% similar?

Tags: javascript, arrays, statistics

This is inspired by a Codecadamey project, where I'm learning JavaScript.

The problem is meant to simulate a simple DNA strand. It has 15 positions in the array, and those elements are either an `A`, `T`, `C`, or `G` to represent DNA bases.
There are no limits to the amount of times a single letter (base) can show up in the array.

I create 30 arrays that are made up of at least 60% `C` and/or `G` in any of the positions, these are meant to represent strong DNA strands.

I compare the strands to each other to see what % match they are. I consider a 'match' being true when there is the same base at the same position `thisDNA[i] === comparisonDNA[i]`

When I test a batch of 30 of these 'strong' samples to see the best and worst match levels, I find the results very tightly grouped (I ran it 3,000 times and the highest was 87%, lowest 53%), yet it is very easy for me to concieve of two samples that will survive that are a 0% match:

```
const sample1 = AGACCGCGCGTGGAG
const sample2 = TCTGGCGCGCACCTC
```

(obviously I've cheated by building these to be a 0% match and not randomly generating them)

Here's the full code: https://gist.github.com/AidaP1/0770307979e00d4e8d3c83decc0f7771

My question is as follows: Why is the grouping of matches so tight? Why do I not see anything below a 53% match after running the test thousands of times?

Full code:

```js
// Returns a random DNA base
const returnRandBase = () => {
  const dnaBases = ['A', 'T', 'C', 'G']
  return dnaBases[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)]
}

// Returns a random single stand of DNA containing 15 bases
const mockUpStrand = () => {
  const newStrand = []
  for (let i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    newStrand.push(returnRandBase())
  }
  return newStrand
}

const pAequorFactory = (num, arr) => { //factory function for new strand specimen
  return {
    specimenNum: num,
    dna: arr,
    mutate() {
      //console.log(`old dna: ${this.dna}`) //checking log
      let randomBaseIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.dna.length) /// chooses a location to exchange the base
      let newBase = returnRandBase()
      while (newBase === this.dna[randomBaseIndex]) { // Rolls a new base until newBase !== current base at that position
        newBase = returnRandBase()
      }
      this.dna[randomBaseIndex] = newBase;
      //console.log(`New dna: ${this.dna}`) //checking log
      return this.dna;
    },
    compareDNA(pAequor) { // compare two strands and output to the console
      let thisDNA = this.dna;
      let compDNA = pAequor.dna;
      let matchCount = 0
      for (i = 0; i < this.dna.length; i++) { //cycles through each array and log position + base matches on matchCount
        if (thisDNA[i] === compDNA[i]) {
          matchCount += 1;
        };
      };
      let percMatch = Math.round(matchCount / this.dna.length * 100) //multiply by 100 to make 0.25 display as 25 in console log
      console.log(`specimen #${this.specimenNum} and specimen #${pAequor.specimenNum} are a ${percMatch}% DNA match.`)
      return percMatch;
    },
    compareDNAbulk(pAequor) { //as above, but does not log to console. Used for large arrays in findMostRelated()
      let thisDNA = this.dna;
      let compDNA = pAequor.dna;
      let matchCount = 0
      for (i = 0; i < this.dna.length; i++) {
        if (thisDNA[i] === compDNA[i]) {
          matchCount += 1;
        };
      };
      let percMatch = Math.round(matchCount / this.dna.length * 100) //multiply by 100 to make 0.25 display as 25 in console log
      return percMatch;
    },
    willLikelySurvive() { // looks for >= 60% of bases as either G or C
      let countCG = 0;
      this.dna.forEach(base => {
        if (base === 'C' || base === 'G') {
          countCG += 1;
        }
      })
      //console.log(countCG) // testing
      //console.log(this.dna) // testing
      return countCG / this.dna.length >= 0.6
    },
    complementStrand() {
      return this.dna.map(base => {
        switch (base) {
          case 'A':
            return 'T';
          case 'T':
            return 'A';
          case 'C':
            return 'G';
          case 'G':
            return 'C';
        }
      })
    } //close method
  } // close object
} // close factory function

function generatepAequorArray(num) { // Generatess 'num' pAequor that .willLikelySurvive() = true
  let pAequorArray = []; //result array
  for (i = 0; pAequorArray.length < num; i++) {
    let newpAequor = pAequorFactory(i, mockUpStrand()); // runs factory until there are 30 items in the result array
    if (newpAequor.willLikelySurvive() === true) {
      pAequorArray.push(newpAequor)
    }
  }
  return pAequorArray;
}

function findMostRelated(array) { // champion/challenger function to find the most related specimens
  let winningScore = 0;
  let winner1;
  let winner2;
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for (let j = i; j < array.length; j++) // j = i to halve the number of loops. i = 0, j = 5 is the same as i = 5, j = 0
      if (i !== j) { // Do not check specimen against itself
        let currentScore = array[i].compareDNAbulk(array[j]);
        if (currentScore > winningScore) { // Challenger becomes the champion if they are a closer match
          winningScore = currentScore;
          winner1 = array[i].specimenNum;
          winner2 = array[j].specimenNum;
        }
      }
  }

  let resultArray = [winner1, winner2, winningScore] // stored together for easy return
  //console.log(`The most related specimens are specimen #${winner1} and specimen #${winner2}, with a ${winningScore}% match.`)
  return resultArray
}



function multiArray(loops) { //test by running finding the closest match in 30 random 'will survive' samples, repaeated 1000 times. Returns the highest and lowest match across the 1000 runs
  let highScore = 0;
  let lowScore = 100
  for (let i = 0; i < loops; i++) {
    let pAequorArray = generatepAequorArray(30);
    let currentArray = findMostRelated(pAequorArray);
    highScore = Math.max(highScore, currentArray[2])
    lowScore = Math.min(lowScore, currentArray[2])
  }
  return results = {
    'high score': highScore,
    'low score': lowScore
  }
}

console.log(multiArray(10000))
```

Comment: Apologies - added

Comment: I've added a snippet to your question. If you could add a line or two showing how the code is run such that you get the results you speak of, that would help others reproduce it, and understand why it isn't working the way you think.

Comment: Thank you for that, I'll add it that way in future. I've called the function at the bottom too